# Trying to get totals AND percentages from MongoDB (using MapReduce)

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I've got documents that store visits to particular pages, that basically look like this (in reality there are more data points, but this should get the point across):

```
[
  {
   page: "home",
   timeStamp: 1417457320
  },
  {
   page: "service",
   timeStamp: 1417457323
  },
  {
   page: "service",
   timeStamp: 1417457325
  }
]
```

I'm trying to report on two things:  Each page's total number of page views per day, and each page's percentage of the total page views per day.  I'm looking for something like:

```
{
  date: 1417392000000,
  page: "home",
  visits: 123,
  percentageOfTotalVisits: .3
}
```

This article (http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/) got me to the totals pretty quickly, but I'm stuck trying to get the percentage of total.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your results are on `per day` basis, you need to `group` the records by the `date`. And then perform the computation. The map-reduce functions may be written as below:

The `map` function:

- Emit the combination of the year, month and date as the key.
- The value being the page name.

The date, year and day information is extracted from the timestamps before being emitted.

```
var map = function(){
var date = new Date(this.timeStamp);
var year = date.getYear();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var key = day+""+month+""+year;
emit(key,{"page":this.page});
}
```

The reduce function:

- Keep track of the number of unique pages for the particular key.
- Once the count per page is collected, the percentage is calculated.

The `result` is returned per key.

```
var reduce = function(id,obj){
    var result = {};
    var totalCount = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        if(result[obj[i].page]){
            result[obj[i].page].visits++; 
        }
        else{
            result[obj[i].page] = {"visits":1,"percentageOfTotalVisits":0};
        }
        totalCount++;
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(result);
    for(var j=0;j<keys.length;j++)
    {
        result[keys[j]].percentageOfTotalVisits = 
                             result[keys[j]].visits/totalCount;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Invoke map reduce on the collection.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: "out"})
```

Sample o/p: on `db.out.find().pretty()`,

```
{
        "_id" : "17070",
        "value" : {
                "home" : {
                        "visits" : 1,
                        "percentageOfTotalVisits" : 0.3333333333333333
                },
                "service" : {
                        "visits" : 2,
                        "percentageOfTotalVisits" : 0.6666666666666666
                }
        }
}
```